# DNSの再帰問い合わせについて

Tags: dns

DNSの名前解決について、DNSの入門書を読みながら勉強していますが、一部のwebサイトに対する再帰問い合わせの動きが理解できず、質問になります。

`www.yahoo.co.jp`ですが下記コマンドより`www.yahoo.co.jp`の実体は`edge12.g.yimg.jp`となるかと思います。

```
# dig www.yahoo.co.jp CNAME

; <<>> DiG 9.18.8 <<>> www.yahoo.co.jp CNAME
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56387
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.yahoo.co.jp.               IN      CNAME

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.yahoo.co.jp.        823     IN      CNAME   edge12.g.yimg.jp.

;; Query time: 237 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 14 22:45:25 JST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 72
```

さらに`edge12.g.yimg.jp`の再帰問い合わせの過程を見ると以下のようになり、`gns12.yahoo.co.jp`が`edge12.g.yimg.jp`のAレコードを返しています。

この2つはドメインが異なりますが、`gns12.yahoo.co.jp`のゾーンファイルに別ドメインである`edge12.g.yimg.jp`のAレコードが登録されているということでしょうか？
具体的なゾーンファイルの設定のイメージが湧かず、気になってまして、質問になります。

```
# dig edge12.g.yimg.jp +trace
（中略）
yimg.jp.                86400   IN      NS      ns02.yahoo.co.jp.
yimg.jp.                86400   IN      NS      ns11.yahoo.co.jp.
yimg.jp.                86400   IN      NS      ns12.yahoo.co.jp.
yimg.jp.                86400   IN      NS      ns01.yahoo.co.jp.
B9CCVLLHT15JM5HET57BQ8MLBAAKPI82.jp. 900 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - B9GCLVHJOFB3318PIQ42MAJLDH459SFM NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
B9CCVLLHT15JM5HET57BQ8MLBAAKPI82.jp. 900 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 900 20231106174503 20231007174503 36861 jp. dbe98ICkxLlrln/47C+fSEY2lvGmFhPge6+tRgC3ih9wOhN51D5TZDQ0 /3ghg7GXh5DeHqGnUOWS7Z+X+KF3b23WhiwPvBMjuqBbWtIz5nWsnbit RJoMD+DfzB9taTGiTPNu4EHPkxu0GzKraH/h94irCJL+8VOvVD9lxtQO TB0=
76D1KQ2PHDOF1HL2T85QVFLTR2JCEVC4.jp. 900 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - 76FE1NU4A5PHIMGP9ATJFEB0DKKGN6AE TXT RRSIG
76D1KQ2PHDOF1HL2T85QVFLTR2JCEVC4.jp. 900 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 900 20231106174503 20231007174503 36861 jp. UdM3PAWk58uO6phWIOM0z82vmXhQVIqxG0fnSfNzL2dPF/llRmOlFpjf aclOaArXyjm44m2R1980Rb8+Kl+j+ZqFlt/esZRlEixJE+Ed3Ir0RZp9 TxcFn88gExjqnApSh16v/mHCf6GASX7LJkx8ePpozTQtpcvq8v32VL4Q aU0=
;; Received 714 bytes from 210.138.175.244#53(d.dns.jp) in 76 ms

g.yimg.jp.              900     IN      NS      gns02.yahoo.co.jp.
g.yimg.jp.              900     IN      NS      gns12.yahoo.co.jp.
;; Received 124 bytes from 118.151.254.133#53(ns01.yahoo.co.jp) in 68 ms

edge12.g.yimg.jp.       60      IN      A       183.79.219.252
;; Received 61 bytes from 124.83.255.100#53(gns12.yahoo.co.jp) in 72 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> この2つはドメインが異なりますが、gns12.yahoo.co.jpのゾーンファイルに別ドメインであるedge12.g.yimg.jpのAレコードが登録されているということでしょうか？

DNSサーバのホスト名と、そのDNSサーバがどのゾーンを持っているかは無関係です。また、DNSサーバは1台で複数のゾーン情報を持つことができます。

例えば、私が持ってるドメインのDNSサーバは aiden.ns.cloudflare.comだったりns-cloud-c1.googledomains.comだったりしますが、当然が持ってるのがcloudflare.comだったりgoogledomains.comなわけはないですし、これらのサーバには私のもの以外の多数のドメインも乗っています。もっと言うと、cloudflare.comとかgoogledomains.comのゾーン情報はこのサーバには(多分)ありません。

というわけで、

1. gns12.yahoo.co.jpにはyahoo.co.jpのゾーン情報がある
2. しかし、edge12.g.yimg.jpにも応答する
3. yahoo.co.jpのゾーン情報にedge12.g.yimg.jpも書かれている？

という想像をされているようですが、

1. gns12.yahoo.co.jpにyahoo.co.jpのゾーン情報があるとは限らないし、あろうがなかろうが関係ない。
2. g.yimg.jp(またはyimg.jp)のゾーン情報はありedge12.g.yimg.jpが定義されている。

が答えです。

蛇足ですが、ゾーンファイルが「ファイル」なのは実装の都合で、必ずしもファイルでなければならないということはありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

「権威DNSサーバのホスト名（FQDN）」と、「権威DNSサーバのゾーン情報」は無関係な場合もありうると理解しました。
ただ、理解があっているかを確認するために、追加で確認させてください。
例えば別々のドメインのdomain1.com（A社管理）とdomain2.com（B社管理）があるとして
domain1.comのネームサーバは必ずしもns1.domain1.comみたいな名前というわけではなくns1.doamin2.comみたいに別ドメイン内（B社の管理ドメイン内）に存在するケースがあるということでしょうか？
この場合、domain1.comのドメインに帰属する各種サーバ（www.domain1.comやdomain1.comのメールサーバなど）はA社で管理するが、DNSについてはB社のdomain2.comのにて管理する（サービス利用）、みたいな構成が取れるということでしょうか？

Comment: レジストラ、権威DNSを提供してもらってる事業者、ドメインと紐付いたサービスが乗っている事業者、は通常それぞれ無関係です。ただし、契約形態によっては一体となっていて分離できないなど制約がある場合もあり得ます。ドメインに対する「管理」という言葉の理解がおそらく正確ではないと思われるので、「イメージとしては多分間違ってない」とお答えするのが限界です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> `gns12.yahoo.co.jp`が`edge12.g.yimg.jp`のAレコードを返しています。
> この2つはドメインが異なりますが、`gns12.yahoo.co.jp`のゾーンファイルに別ドメインである`edge12.g.yimg.jp`のAレコードが登録されているということでしょうか？

解釈が違っていて、

- × `gns12.yahoo.co.jp`が`edge12.g.yimg.jp`のAレコードを返す
- ○ `gns12.yahoo.co.jp`の名前解決した結果得られるIPアドレスのサーバーが`edge12.g.yimg.jp`のAレコードを返す

です。つまり、DNSサーバーに付けられている名前と、そのDNSサーバーが持つゾーンに依存関係はありません。
逆に、DNSサーバーが自身のゾーン内にのみ名前定義されていたとすると、鶏と卵になってしまってDNSサーバーのIPアドレスを得ることができなくなります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。